# Python MagicMock attribute is static

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

Consider I have to unit-test the following function:

```
def f(A):
    tasks = []

    for i in range(0, 3):
        task = A.tasks.create()
        task.attr = i

        tasks.append(task)

    return tasks
```

When I mock `A` argument of `f` function, this happens:

```
>>> A = mock.MagicMock()
>>> tasks = f(A)

>>> for task in tasks:
>>>    print(task.attr)

Out: 2 2 2
```

I expected the following output: `0 1 2`, why do I get that and how can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `A` is a `MagicMock`, so is `A.tasks` and `A.tasks.create`. When you call the last one, it always returns a reference to the *same* `MagicMock` instance, so `task.attr = i` overwrites the `attr` attribute of the same `MagicMock`. `tasks` is a list of three references to the same `MagicMock` instance.

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> A = mock.MagicMock()
>>> A.tasks.create()
<MagicMock name='mock.task.create()' id='4486337536'>
>>> A.tasks.create()
<MagicMock name='mock.task.create()' id='4486337536'>
>>> A.tasks.create()
<MagicMock name='mock.task.create()' id='4486337536'>
```

(Note the id is the same for all three.)

One way to get a new mock task each time you call `create` is to explicitly assign `MagicMock` to the `create` attribute of the `tasks` mock:

```
>>> A = mock.MagicMock()
>>> A.tasks.create = mock.MagicMock
>>> A.task.create()
<MagicMock id='4485133648'>
>>> A.task.create()
<MagicMock id='4485176176'>
```